# Trouble getting signalR to work with requireJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs, signalr

I am having difficulty trying to get signalr to work with requirejs. This is my code I have but I get the following error:

`_Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>._`

Code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// requirejs configuration setup
requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: '@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}Scripts/modules", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))', // this might need to change as it depends on the number of / in the url...?
        paths: {
                'jquery': '../jquery-1.9.0',
                'bootstrap': '../bootstrap',
                'knockout': '../knockout-2.2.1',
                'noext': '../noext',
                'sigr': '../jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2'
        },
        shim: {
                "sigr": {
                        deps: ['jquery']
                },
                "noext!signalr/hubs": {
                        deps: ['sigr']
                }
        }
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why or how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get require to work with requirejs..I followed the tutorial on http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html on how to plugin jquery and added signal references for this to work

```
require(["jquery", "jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta","jquery.signalr-1.0.0-rc2","/signalr/hubs"], 
    function($) {
    }
);
```

I think you have to modify your configuration to do either of the following
Option1:

```
paths: {
    'jquery': '../jquery-1.9.0',
    'bootstrap': '../bootstrap',
    'knockout': '../knockout-2.2.1',
    'noext': '../noext',
    'sigr': '../jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2'
    'hubs': '/signalr/hubs'
},
```

Option2:

```
shim: {
    "sigr": {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    "noext!**/**signalr/hubs": {
        deps: ['sigr']
    }
}
```